# Python Django signals 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, signals

I creating badminton sport app in Django where you can create matches, etc..
What I am trying to do now is update matches_played from my models.py via signals.

Here is my signals.py:

```
class Player(models.Model):
   ...
   matches_played = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
   ...

class Match(models.Model):
    player_home = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='player_home')
    player_away = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, related_name='player_away')
    player_home_sets = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    player_away_sets = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my signals.py:

```
def add_match_count(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    home_player_sets = instance.player_home_sets
    away_player_sets = instance.player_away_sets
       if home_player_sets > 0 or away_player_sets > 0:
           instance.player_home.matches_played += 1
           instance.player_away.matches_played += 1
           instance.player_home.matches_played.save()
```

If I edit any match I receive error: 'int' object has no attribute 'instance'. 
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
instance.player_home.matches_played.save()
```

makes no sense. The `.matches_played` attribute is an `int`, and an `int` has no `.save()` method. You likely want to replace this with:

```
def add_match_count(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    home_player_sets = instance.player_home_sets
    away_player_sets = instance.player_away_sets
       if home_player_sets > 0 or away_player_sets > 0:
           instance.player_home.matches_played += 1
           instance.player_home.save()
           instance.player_away.matches_played += 1
           instance.player_away.save()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help.